# Boost.Bind and template member function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, boost-bind

I have a function `Change` that takes two parameters in an template class as such. The boost::bind gives an error `error: invalid use of non-static member function`

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>


enum class EventType
{
    UNKNOWN
};


// Note: All Observers must implement OnNotify for any subject types they wish to observe
//       Any unimplemented subject types that are used will result in a compiler error
template <typename Base> class Observer
{
public:
    Observer() : obsID_(obsIDTracker_++) {}
    template <typename T> void OnNotifyImpl(T &subject, EventType event)
    {
        static_cast<Base *>(this)->OnNotify(subject, event);
    }
    int GetID() const
    {
        return obsID_;
    }
private:
    int obsID_;
    static int obsIDTracker_;
};
template <typename base> int Observer<base>::obsIDTracker_ = 0;

// Recursive helper structs for implementing calls to all observers held within subjects
template <int N, typename T, typename... Args> struct NotifyHelper
{
    static void NotifyImpl(T &subject, EventType event,
                           std::tuple<Args...> &obs)
    {
        std::get<sizeof...(Args) - N>(obs).OnNotifyImpl(subject, event);
        NotifyHelper<N - 1, T, Args...>::NotifyImpl(subject, event, obs);
    }
};
template <typename T, typename... Args> struct NotifyHelper<0, T, Args...>
{
    static void NotifyImpl(T &subject, EventType event,
                           std::tuple<Args...> &obs) {}
};

// See MakeSubject function for instance usage
template <typename T, typename... Obs> class Subject
{
public:
    static const int NumberOfObservers = sizeof...(Obs);
    Subject(std::tuple<Obs &...> &&obs) : observers(obs) {}

    void NotifyAll(EventType event)
    {
        NotifyHelper<NumberOfObservers, T, Obs &...>::NotifyImpl(
            *static_cast<T *>(this), event, observers);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Obs &...> observers;
};

//class PressureInterface
//{
//public:
//    virtual ~PressureInterface() {}
//    virtual void Change(int value) {}
//};

// CRTP Abstract Base class for implementing static subject.
// Example Subclass Usage -- Pressure Sensor:
template <typename... Obs>
class Pressure : public Subject<Pressure<Obs...>, Obs...> //,public PressureInterface
{
public:
    typedef Subject<Pressure<Obs...>, Obs...> BaseType;
    Pressure(std::tuple<Obs &...> &&observers, int pressure)
        : BaseType(std::move(observers)), pressure_(pressure) {}
    void Change(int value)
    {
        pressure_ = value;
        this->NotifyAll(EventType::UNKNOWN);
    }
    int GetPressure() const
    {
        return pressure_;
    }

private:
    int pressure_;
};

// CRTP Abstract Base class for implementing static subject.
// Example Subclass Usage -- Printing Observer:
class Printer : public Observer<Printer>
{
public:
    Printer() : timesTriggered_(0) {}
    template <typename... Args>
    void OnNotify(Pressure<Args...> &subject, EventType event)
    {
        std::cout << "Observer ID: " << this->GetID() << std::endl;
        switch (event)
        {
        case EventType::UNKNOWN:
        {
            std::cout << "Unknown Event -- Event #" << timesTriggered_++
                      << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Pressure: " << subject.GetPressure() << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
        }
    }

private:
    int timesTriggered_;
};


// Binding function for use with MakeSubject
//   Arguments: observer objects to observe subject notifications
//   Return:    tuple of references to observers
template <typename... Obs> std::tuple<Obs &...> BindObservers(Obs &... obs)
{
    return std::tuple<Obs &...>(obs...);
}

// Creator to ease subject creation
//   Template Arguments: Subject subclass type
//   Arguments: Result from BindObservers
//              Any constructor arguments for Subject subclass
//   Return:    Subject subclass
// Example Usage:
// auto pressure = MakeSubject<Pressure>(BindObservers(printerObs), initialPressure);
template <template <typename...> class T, typename... Args, typename... Obs>
T<Obs...> MakeSubject(std::tuple<Obs &...> &&obs, Args &&... args)
{
    return T<Obs...>(std::move(obs), args...);
}

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

int main()
{
    Printer printerObs1;
    Printer printerObs2;

    const int initialPressure = 1;

    auto pressure = MakeSubject<Pressure>(
                        BindObservers(printerObs1, printerObs2), initialPressure);

    //Compiler gives error here:
    boost::bind(&Pressure<Printer, Printer>::Change, pressure.Change, _1, 12);

    pressure.Change(12);

    pressures[0].change(2000);
}
```

Comment: `Pressure<Printer, Printer, Printer>*` is not a function pointer signature. Edit the question with the signature of the function `Change`

Comment: found a similar question (but not a one using template): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756331/function-pointers-generate-invalid-use-of-non-static-member-function-error

Comment: What is symbolQuotes2ObserverMap? You have provided only observerMap variable.

Comment: That was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: I changed the code to be 100% self contained. Now you can copy it and see the error for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need in using `boost::ref`. To call a boost::bind with pointer to method you need to provide `this` pointer of the object that the method will be called:

```
ioService.post(boost::bind(&Pressure<Printer, Printer, Printer>::change, observerMap[astring], astring, v));
```

Comment: See the new expanded example above. That code combination also doesn't work.

Comment: @Ivan You doing it wrong, pass pointer to object as a second argument, without a `.Change` part.

Comment: boost::bind(&Pressure<Printer,Printer>::Change, &pressure, _1, 12); also gives error

Comment: @Ivan You don't need the _1, you have only one parameter now.

Comment: Gotcha. Got it to work. I am also misunderstanding the need for _1, _2 etc... Thanks!